# Visualize results/coordinates of shortest path algorithms

Tags: python, geojson

I am working on a navigation system and want to visually check results of my calculations. (Dijkstra, A*, etc.)

What are my options without getting into Google Maps API, Javascript, etc.?

For the most part every query gives me a list of coordinates:

```
[[53.4704344, 9.9145282], [53.4704483, 9.9152652], [53.4704704, 9.9164389], [53.4704818, 9.9169074]]
```

Right now I build GeoJSON linestring I paste into GeoJSONLint.com which starts getting annoying.

Comment: Do you need the underlying map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the requirements, two things that immediately come to mind are:

- `matplotlib` maps: http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html
- GeoJSON on http://gist.github.com: https://github.com/blog/1576-gist-meets-geojson

I would probably use gist first, as it's all git-able, zoomable, shows streets, etc.
Which is better probably depends on your data (especially the spatial scale).

Comment: Thanks, your 3rd link is referring to geojson.io. That is great. Something like this is possible: http://geojson.io/#data=data:application/json,%7B%22coordinates%22%3A%20%5B%5B9.9145282%2C%2053.4704344%5D%2C%20%5B9.9152652%2C%2053.4704483%5D%2C%20%5B9.9164389%2C%2053.4704704%5D%2C%20%5B9.9169074%2C%2053.4704818%5D%5D%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22LineString%22%7D . Exactly what I need.